# Android: Catch error/exception on older API devices

Tags: android

I'm using `AudioTrack.setVolume` which requires API 21. I have `minSdkVersion` set to 16. Is below the correct way to handle catching errors on older devices?

```
    try {
        audioTrack.setVolume(volume);
    }catch (Exception e){
        // Ignore - setVolume requires API 21 and minSdkVersion is set to 16
        // Also ignore any IllegalStateExceptions
    }catch(Error e){
        // Ignore
    }
```

I have a similar code block for `AudioTrack.Builder` which requires API 23. This is throwing `Didn't find class "android.media.AudioTrack$Builder` errors despite the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *try-catch* you can check the version of API in this way:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
         audioTrack.setVolume(volume);
    }
```